# Retrive data according a value where colum is imploded by <br> in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in my table whose name is `users`. I need to retrieve rows from this table.

The values in the `users` column are in following format: `45br67br89br96`.
Means the users column in the table is imploded by `br` (line break)

I need to retrieve the row of table if certain value exist in the column, for example 
I need to retrieve the row where users contain 89.

How can I write a query for this?

Comment: Just have to say that is a horrible way to store a set of integer based user data. I would give that data structure a rethink if at all possible

Comment: You should really redesign your database. Ask Google for "Database Normalization"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator. It performs simple comparison of given expression (e.g. value of field in a column) against the given pattern. In your case, the pattern is user id (e.g. `89`) and the expressions is column name (`users`):

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `users` LIKE "%89%"
```

The `%` character is very useful. It matches any number of characters, even zero characters. (The other one is `_` - it matches exactly one character.)
The above is an example of course. For normal usage in PHP script you will have to pass the pattern as a variable:

```
<?php
$i_search_for = 89;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `users` LIKE "%' . $i_search_for . '%"';
?>
```

I also recommend you this lecture: [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 0):

Just query the entire value of the cell and apply preg_match_all in order to extract all user ids.

```
$str ="45br67br89br96";

preg_match_all('#([0-9])+#', $str, $array, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$matches = $array[0];

foreach($matches as $var)
{    
   print($var." ");
}
```

Outputs:
45
67
89
96

Comment: This solution retrieves all rows to PHP and then performs the search what is nonsense regarding performance.

Comment: I understand the question, as when he tries to extract user ids from a cell entry and not all rows of a colum.

Comment: Thak you for all replies but avtually  i need a mysql solution for this

Comment: Do you mean a pure MYSQL solution? This sounds odd to me. So, why did you tag the thread with PHP? Why don't you read the corresponding cell and process the extraction with PHP as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I would explode the value and then search for the user.

Like so:

```
$arr = explode("br", $users_value);
$row = array_search('89', $arr);
```